# Doctrine INSTANCE OF conditional JOIN

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I need to get some nested entities with doctrine QueryBuilder (or DQL)

First, I have one common abstract entity 'Item', and two herited entities: 'Directory' and 'File'. So…
- Item can have a parentDirectory (so Directory and File can have)
- Only a Directory can have many 'Item' (so, can contain Directories and Files).

```
abstract class Item {
…
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CLIENT\ADV\BackendBundle\Entity\Directory", mappedBy="items")
 */
private $directories;
…

class File extends Item {…

class Directory extends Item {
…
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CLIENT\ADV\BackendBundle\Entity\Item", inversedBy="directories")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="directories_items")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name": "ASC"})
 */
private $items;
```

Next, I have a method in my Repository, with a list of ID as parameter. I need to get these ID's entities, with all their children:

```
class DirectoryRepository extends ItemRepository {

public function getItems(Array $ids) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb
        ->addSelect('i1')
        ->where($qb->expr()->in($qb->getRootAliases()[0].'.id', $ids))
        ->orderBy('d.name', 'ASC')
        ->join($qb->getRootAliases()[0].'.items', 'i1')
        ->addOrderBy('i1.name', 'ASC')
        ->leftJoin('i1.items', 'i2') <-- try to get children of children…
        ->addSelect('i2')
        ->andWhere('i1 INSTANCE OF directory') <-- condition does not work
        ;
    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

My problem is that a File has no association 'Items' (only Directory have it):

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 106 near 'i2 WHERE d.id': Error: Class CLIENT\ADV\BackendBundle\Entity\Item has no association named items

I tried in DQL too… But no more issue.
This JOIN must be effective on entity ONLY if it is a Directory, but a File.
Do someone have a solution?

…Next step will be hard: build a recursive way to get deep tree of 'Item' children… ^^

Comment: Have you tried to get the raw SQL and try it directly? How does the raw SQL looks like? Can you add it to the OP?

Comment: I can not get the raw SQL with $qb->getQuery()->getSql() (and not able to construct it at myself… not enough pro in SQL) because of this error happening before :p

Comment: Here is what I tried in DQL : 
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
  'SELECT d, i1 FROM VeximADVBackendBundle:Directory d
  LEFT JOIN d.items i1
  WHERE d.id IN (\''.implode("','", $ids).'\')
  ORDER BY d.name ASC, i1.name ASC
  '
 );
return $query->getArrayResult();

Comment: AFAIK you can not do `INSTANCE OF` inside the query itself (maybe I am wrong not sure) so I would recommend you go trough your "next step" and build a recursive way

Comment: Thanks ! I Asked a friend, pro in SQL… I will sent his response if OK…